# How do I get rid of blank spaces that appear at the end of Tspan elements in svg?

Tags: javascript, html, xslt, svg

I'm implementing `svg` in an `xslt` transformation. As part of this, I have to put a url in a box. However, the box can only be a certain width, so I wrote a function in javascript for word wrapping, since SVG doesn't support word wrapping. Basically, the javascript is splitting the string into five sections and putting them in different `tspan` elements. However, at the end of each `tspan` element, a blank space is appearing. This makes copying and pasting the link impossible, which is essentially the function of the info url. How do I get rid of this blank space?

I'm very new to SVG and XSLT.

Here's the javascript word wrapping function:

```
function wrapURLText(url){
  var char="";
  var urlString = url;
  var bufferString ="";
  var stringLength = urlString.length;
  var bufferStringLength=stringLength;
  var charCaps="";
  var charsize=0;
  var tempStringSize=0;
  var i=0;
  var j=0;

  while (j<5)
  {
    charsize=0;
    tempStringSize=0;
    bufferString="";
    i=0;
    while (i<bufferStringLength) {

          char = urlString.charAt(i);
          charCaps = char.toUpperCase();
          if (char >= '0' && char <= '9') {
            charsize=6.5;
          }
          else if (char==charCaps) {
            charsize=11.5;
          }
          else if (char!=charCaps) {
            charsize=8.6;
          }
          else charsize=5;

          tempStringSize += charsize;
          if (tempStringSize<=400) {
            bufferString=bufferString.concat(char);
          }
          if (i==stringLength) {
            return;
          }
          if (tempStringSize>400) {
            bufferString=bufferString.concat(char);
            i++;
            break;
          }
          i++;
    }

    j++
    $('#urlText'+j).text(bufferString);
    urlString= urlString.substring(i,stringLength);        
  }
}
```

Here's the SVG it's referring to (in an `xslt` transformation):

```
<g>
  <rect id="infoURL" width="400" height="120" x="35" y="270" fill="#ECECEC" stroke="#CCCCCC" rx="3" ry="3"/>
  <text id="urlText" class="infoItems" text-anchor="left" style="font-family: Arial; font-size:16; stroke: #333333; fill:#333333;" x="40" y="290">
    <tspan id="urlText1" class="infoItems" text-anchor="left" style="font-family: Arial; font-size:16; stroke: #333333; fill:#333333;" x="40" y="290" />
    <tspan id="urlText2" class="infoItems" text-anchor="left" style="font-family: Arial; font-size:16; stroke: #333333; fill:#333333;" x="40" y="310" />
    <tspan id="urlText3" class="infoItems" text-anchor="left" style="font-family: Arial; font-size:16; stroke: #333333; fill:#333333;" x="40" y="330" />
    <tspan id="urlText4" class="infoItems" text-anchor="left" style="font-family: Arial; font-size:16; stroke: #333333; fill:#333333;" x="40" y="350" />
    <tspan id="urlText5" class="infoItems" text-anchor="left" style="font-family: Arial; font-size:16; stroke: #333333; fill:#333333;" x="40" y="370" />
  </text>
</g>
```

I would be very  grateful to anyone that can help!

Comment: Don't add blank spaces between the tspan elements if you don't want them

Comment: Wait, what? I don't think I have any blank space between them?

Comment: you've around 6 blank spaces at the beginning of every         <tspan> element line (because of your indenting of the XML) + a carriage return at the end of the previous line.

Comment: I changed it so there's no space between the tags, no change.

Comment: Update the question then so we can see what you did.

Comment: Updated. Sorry, new to stackoverflow

Comment: Is the SVG you are showing the literal result from an XSL transformation? This transformation might add indentation, especially if you're using `<xsl:output indent="yes"/>`. --- I'd suggest having a look at HTML inside SVG's [`<foreignObject>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) element. This way, you can have proper word wrapping "for free".  That's not really on topic of your whitespace question, but might still be helpful.

Comment: I was never able to get foreignobject to work properly. I don't believe xsl:output indent is being used either though. And it should be the literal result? Not 100% sure.